# Fill a path node in Draw2d touch

Tags: svg, raphael, draw2d-js

Im trying to make an arrow joining a rect and a path (triangle). This is my code:

```
var svgCarga = [
  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">',
  '<rect opacity="0" height="50" width="50" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>',
  '<rect stroke="#000" height="29.875" width="4" y="6.3125" x="23" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000"/>',
  '<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000" d="m17.41375,36.090939l7.4375,10l7.4375,-10l-14.875,0z" stroke-width="1"/>',
  '</svg>',
].join();


Carga = draw2d.SVGFigure.extend({
  NAME: 'Carga',
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.width = 65;
    this.height = 65;
  },
  getSVG: function() {
    return svgCarga;
  }
});
```

As you can see, the path has an attribute: fill="#000000" but when is rendered shows fill="none"... if i change this attribute manually, shows the path filled.

[image: Debugger]
[image: View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what do you want to do exactly.

I think you can't fill an SVG Path in Draw2D for now (*keep in mind that the SVGFigure import is currently very limited*)

```
'<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000" d="m17.41375,36.090939l7.4375,10l7.4375,-10l-14.875,0z" stroke-width="1"/>'
```

You can use polygon to do that, like this:

```
'<polygon points="25,45 15,35 35,35" fill="#000000" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" />'
```

Hope it's what you want :)

Reference:

```
http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_5/#!/guide/extending_svg_figure
```